# Parsing XML / RSS from URL using Java Script

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

Hi i want to parse xml/rss from a live url like http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/entertainment  using pure Java Script(not jquery). I have googled a lot. Nothing worked for me. can any one help with a working piece of code.

Comment: What's wrong with using jQuery? (it makes things a lot easier)

Comment: Sorry.. I have to use only Java Script in this task.

Comment: Do not listen to the jQuery fanboys. When all you know is jQuery, every problem looks `$(olvable)`. But I need to point out: it is _JavaScript_ (which jQuery is written in), and that is [only half the truth](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

(You cannot have googled a lot.) Once you have [worked around the Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy#Workarounds), and if the resource is served with an [XML MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_and_MIME) (which [it is in this case](http://web-sniffer.net/), `text/xml`), you can do the following:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open("GET", "http://feed.example/", true);
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200)
  {
    var doc = x.responseXML;
    // …
  }
};
x.send(null);
```

(See also [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX), and the [XMLHttpRequest Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/) specification [Working Draft] for other event-handler properties.)

In essence: **No parsing necessary.**  If you then want to access the XML data, use the standard [DOM Level 2+ Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) or [DOM Level 3 XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/) methods, e.g.

```
/* DOM Level 2 Core */
var title = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

/* DOM Level 3 Core */
var title = doc.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent;

/* DOM Level 3 XPath (not using namespaces) */
var title = doc.evaluate('//channel/title/text()', doc, null, 0, null).iterateNext();

/* DOM Level 3 XPath (using namespaces) */
var namespaceResolver = (function () {
  var prefixMap = {
    media: "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/",
    ynews: "http://news.yahoo.com/rss/"
  };

  return function (prefix) {
    return prefixMap[prefix] || null;
  };
}());

var url = doc.evaluate('//media:content/@url', doc, namespaceResolver, 0, null).iterateNext();
```

(See also [JSX:xpath.js](http://pointedears.de/wsvn/JSX/trunk/dom/xpath.js) for a convenient, namespace-aware DOM 3 XPath wrapper that does not use jQuery.)

However, if for some (wrong) reason the MIME type is not an XML MIME type, or if it is not recognized by the DOM implementation as such, you can use one of the parsers built into recent browsers to parse the `responseText` property value.  See [pradeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8238961/855543) for a solution that works in IE/MSXML.  The following should work everywhere else:

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(x.responseText, "text/xml");
```

Proceed as described above.

Use *feature tests* at runtime to determine the correct code branch for a given implementation. The simplest way is:

```
if (typeof DOMParser != "undefined")
{
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  // …
}
else if (typeof ActiveXObject != "undefined")
{
  var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  // …
}
```

See also [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOMParser) and [HTML5: DOM Parsing and Serialization (Working Draft)](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html).

Answer (score 11):

One big problem you might run into is that generally, you cannot get data cross domain. This is big issue with most rss feeds.

The common way to deal with loading data in javascript cross domain is calls JSONP. Basically, this means that the data you are retrieving is wrapped in a javascript callback function. You load the url with a script tag, and you define the function in your code. So when the script loads, it executes the function and passes the data to it as an argument.

The problem with most xml/rss feeds is that services that only provide xml tend not to provide JSONP wrapping capability.

Before you go any farther, check to see if your data source provides a json format and JSONP functionality. That will make this a lot easier.

Now, if your data source *doesn't* provide json and jsonp functionality, you have to get creative.

On relatively easy way to handle this is to use a proxy server. Your proxy runs somewhere under your control, and acts as a middleman to get your data. The server loads your xml, and then your javascript does the requests to it instead. If the proxy server runs on the same domain name then you can just use standard xhr(ajax) requests and you don't have to worry about cross-domain stuff.

Alternatively, your proxy server can wrap the data in a jsonp callback and you can use the method mentioned above.

If you are using jQuery, then xhr and jsonp requests are built-in methods and so make doing the coding very easy. Other common js libraries should also support these. If you are coding all of this from scratch, its a little more work but not terribly difficult.

Now, once you get your data hopefully its just json. Then there's no parsing needed.

However, if you end up having to stick with an xml/rss version, and if you're jQuery, you can simply use jQuery.parseXML http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/.

Answer (score -1):

better convert xml to json. http://jsontoxml.utilities-online.info/

after converting if you need to print json object check this tutorial 
http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp

Comment: Conversion of XML to JSON can be helpful syntactically (shorter, better performing accessors) if done properly – that is, if XML namespaces are considered – but that is unnecessary and the resulting data structure is less flexible than an XML document (JSPath, JSSLT anyone?). (Unfortunately, your first URI is 404-compatible.) BTW, W3Schools (which has nothing to do with the W3C) is a site full of misinformation, best avoided.

Comment: Now that the Web site is back online, I could review the converter. It is really not bad. Namespaces and Unicode are considered; attribute names are "`-`"-prefixed; nodes with the same name are array-ified; even parser errors are serialized. There is room for improvement, though. For example: All serialized values are strings; for boolean attributes you could have saved a bit of overhead with simply `true`, which is part of JSON. And the conversion is not bijective (when it could): toJSON(toXML(json)) != json.

Comment: @NathanSri That first link is dead, can you update your answer?