# AJAX library that supports namespaced xml

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, namespaces

I am looking for an AJAX JavaScript library that supports namespaced xml.

I read dozens of posts on the web (including on stackoverflow) but didn't find a good answer. There are many AJAX examples, but they break as soon as namespaces come into play (it is the case for example with jQuery selectors).

Comment: Can you provide some examples?

Comment: er...examples that break? With jQuery: $(responseXML).find("foo:bar")

Comment: `$("nspace\\:data", xml).find("foo\\:bar").each(function(i) {` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces

Comment: No, I am afraid that's a trick that happened to work because of special circumstances, but is now broken with recent jQuery releases (v 1.7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you are calling an "AJAX JavaScript library" – making HTTP requests is a problem *different* from accessing nodes in a document tree.

If you understand a library as "a collection of resources used to develop software" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing))), then, as part of the *JSX* library, I have written rather compatible¹ wrappers for `XMLHttpRequest` and namespace-aware [DOM Level 3 XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/): [`http.js`](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fhttp.js) and [`xpath.js`](http://pointedears.de/websvn/filedetails.php?repname=JSX&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fxpath.js).

`http.js` supports synchronous and asynchronous processing in the same way, and can even access the local filesystem (if permission is granted).  Because JSX qualifies as a library then, you can use `http.js` and `xpath.js` either separately, with foreign code to complement either one, or together.

You would use them together, for example, as follows. Suppose you had an XML document with resource name `test.xml` like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <res:Response
        xmlns:res="http://domain.example/Response">
      <res:OUTPUT>
        <res:UNDO_COUNT>1.0</res:UNDO_COUNT>
        <res:MSG>Undo complete (No more to undo)</res:MSG>
      </res:OUTPUT>
    </res:Response>
    <res:OUTPUT
        xmlns:res="http://domain.example/Response">
      foo
    </res:OUTPUT>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and you wanted to extract the `1.0` from its `res:UNDO_COUNT` element, you could write:

```
<!-- 1. Include prerequisites and dependencies using Resource Builder (recommended) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="builder.php?src=object,string,http,xpath"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /*
   * 2. Construct the HTTP request wrapper; 
   *    the default is a GET request with asynchronous handling
   */
  var request = new jsx.net.http.Request("test.xml");

  /* 3. Prepare processing of the HTTP response */
  request.setSuccessListener(function (response) {
    /* 5. Get the reference to the XMLDocument object */
    var doc = response.responseXML;

    /* 6. Create the namespace resolver that fits your query best */
    var nsResolver = jsx.xpath.createFullNSResolver(null, doc);

    /* 7. Make the XPath query */
    var nodes = jsx.xpath.evaluate("//res:UNDO_COUNT/text()", doc, nsResolver);

    /*
     * 8. Process the result.  jsx.xpath.evaluate() returns a reference
     * to an Array instance if you do not specify the result type.
     */

    /* "1.0" */
    console.log(nodes[0].data);
  });

  /* 4. Make the HTTP request */
  request.send();
</script>
```

See also: [Parsing XML / RSS from URL using Java Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237923/parsing-xml-rss-from-url-using-java-script/8389440#8389440)

¹ A combination of JSX:`object.js`, `http.js`, and `xpath.js` has been tested positive in Gecko-, WebCore-, MSHTML-based and Opera browsers. However, JSX is *mostly experimental* code for now.

[Testcase](http://PointedEars.de/scripts/test/httprequest), see script console

Constructive feedback is welcome. In addition, JSX is [free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html). (You cannot do a `checkout` yet, but I am working on it.)

Comment: I am interested in both request and response processing (my main issue being the latter). Thanks for the reply, I'll take a look at your wrapper. Did you test it in Internet Explorer 7/8/9? As for the last link, I am afraid there is nothing relevant as soon as namespaces come into play.

Comment: I could not test the HEAD revision of xpath.js (committed today) in IE 7 to 9 yet. I tested it positive in IE 6.0.2800.1106 on Wine, so MSXML's `selectNodes` is supported, and I do not expect surprises in later IE versions (same DOM). As for making HTTP requests, look into JSX:http.js (see edit). That has been tested in the named browsers, including IE 7 and 8 at least, and is powering commercial sites (although those run slightly older JSX revisions, of course).

Comment: @Christophe What do you mean - nothing relevant? RSS/XML uses namespaces. You need a namespace resolver to find those elements with XPath. My previous posting shows how to make and use one. `jsx.xpath.create…NSResolver()` build on that.

Comment: sorry, I'll need to take a closer look. I just saw the use of getElementsByTagName, which will break as soon as namespaces are involved.

Comment: @Christophe I have updated the description and merged the two examples into one use-case, so that you can see better how the scripts can work together.

Comment: Thanks! I need to test it in IE. What is the point of Resource Builder btw?

Comment: Thanks for the points. Resource Builder reduces the script (and style) footprints for the Web (while preserving the code for editing) by removing unnecessary comments, and [reduces the number of HTTP requests](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rtt.html) for each resource type to one. I might even add automated minification later. The ultimate goal is to resolve dependencies automatically without relying on client-side triggered loading (AFAIK, unlike other libraries).

Comment: I have added a link to a *live* testcase.