# Anything wrong with this short XMLHttpRequest declaration?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

In all the AJAX libraries I've checked out, XMLHttpRequest involves a lengthy declaration with tests or try/catch statements.

I need to retrieve XML via a SOAP GET request, and I tested the following declaration successfully in IE7+, Firefox and Chrome:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest()||new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

What am I missing here? Did I overlook some edge cases where my declaration is going to break?

**Edit**

So the second part of the declaration never runs. Does it means that for IE7+/Firefox/Chrome I just need:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Comment: Is it all inside a `try { ... }` block?

Comment: er...no. IE7+, Firefox and Chrome apparently accepted it.

Comment: As already shown in the first answers here, most of those lenghty declarations are there for good reason.  I'd just use YUI, jQuery, or your other favorite JavaScript/AJAX library and be done with it.  Why solve the problem again?  :-)

Comment: As it turns out, I am trying to solve a problem that jQuery doesn't seem to address: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8388889/ajax-library-that-supports-namespaced-xml

Comment: I'd agree with PointedEars's direction on that question:  the XMLHttpRequest should only be used as the transport mechanism, and a separate layer used for navigation of an XML tree.  A few years ago, I created by own "XPathExpression" library that did just this - providing the basic XPath methods that worked with all XPath expressions (that I found) - needing only ~90 lines of code to handle the browser-specific differences - including use of XML namespaces.  I'll see if I can get this code up-to-date and contributed as an answer to your other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` has precendence, so you're executing `new XMLHttpRequest()` and check the *return value*. However, in case `XMLHttpRequest` is not defined, this execution already throws an error. Rather, you want to check whether `XMLHttpRequest` is defined before applying `new`, e.g.:

```
var xhr = typeof XMLHttpRequest === "undefined"
            ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
            : new XMLHttpRequest; // you can leave out the parens with no arguments
```

Comment: doh...thanks pimvdb! I have updated my question, it seems that XMLHttpRequest is enough for my case.

Comment: @Christophe: You are correct by saying the second part (after `||`) does not add anything. `new` always returns an object, which is never falsy.

Comment: In my opinion, returning false would be more useful... Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You gonna miss the case for Internet Explorer versions inferior to 7:

```
new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
```

I think having a function `createRequest()` for example that you don't have to modify and returns the good object depending on the browser, and containing try/catch to handle errors would be a better way to go.