# Parse external XML (rss) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, rss

I want to parse this RSS without Php:

```
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <item>
       <title>Test</title>
       <link>http://www.test.com</link>
       <image>
          <url>http://foo.bar/test.jpg</url>
       </image>
       <description>
       <![CDATA[Description text here!<br><a href="http://www.test.se" target="_blank" rel="external" data-ajax="false">Link!</a></div>]]>
       </description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Can I accomplish this without Php? I'm a complete newbie in jQuery/javascript..
**The XML is here:** http://hundkartan.se/karta/kartdata/cron_webbutiker_mob.xml

I'm going to use this in phonegap so it's an EXTERNAL feed.

Comment: Did you try anything yet, or you expecting to be new to JavaScript forever?

Comment: I've tried several javascripts that I've found with some googleing. None of them has worked yet :/

Comment: jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML / RSS from URL using Java Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237923/parsing-xml-rss-from-url-using-java-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to use json with javascript.
You can convert the XML into a json file with some external script (like this [XML2JSON](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html)).

JSON is natively supported by javascript so access to a member is really simple. For example to obtain all `link` you can simply do:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xml2json.js"></script>
    ...
</head>
...

<body> 
    <script>
    var json = xml2json.parser(XML_file);
    var channel = json.rss.channel;
    var links = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < channel.item.length; i++)
        links.push(channel.item[i].link);
    ...
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```